# How to get average rating using Ajax Rating Tool

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-ajax

My code

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
<cc1:Rating ID="Rating1" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="OnRatingChanged" runat="server"
    StarCssClass="Star" WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star"
    FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar">
</cc1:Rating>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblRatingStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Rating.aspx

```
public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = this.GetData("SELECT ISNULL(AVG(Rating), 0) AverageRating, COUNT(Rating) RatingCount FROM UserRatings");
        Rating1.CurrentRating = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["AverageRating"]);
        lblRatingStatus.Text = string.Format("{0} Users have rated. Average Rating {1}", dt.Rows[0]["RatingCount"], dt.Rows[0]["AverageRating"]);
    }
}

private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}

protected void OnRatingChanged(object sender, RatingEventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserRatings VALUES(@Rating)"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", e.Value);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}

}
```

I found this code online.It is not working. I can not find any errors but it is not inserting records.In this output screen is shows 0 users have rated, Average Rating 0 even after you rate it.
I am new to Ajax and asp.net.If you can give any suggestions it would be helpful 
THANK YOU.

Comment: Is there just one field in the ratings table? Rating? You might want to try `INSERT INTO UserRatings (Rating) VALUES(@Rating)`. You also don't have to close the connection, the Using statement will do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters but you could also try moving the scriptmanager outside of the form. (?)